# modal can't add the second data after i close the first and closed it

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, modal-dialog

```
$('#form-add-Group').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let start = $('#start').val();
        let end = $('#end').val();
        let useFlag = $('#useFlag').val();
        let nameGroup = $('#nameGroup').val();
        let createDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') + '.' + moment().millisecond();

        $.ajax({

            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>canteen/CanteenManagement/addG',
            method: 'post',
            cache: false,
            data: {
                session: '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('id_user') ?>',
                start: start,
                end: end,
                useFlag: useFlag,
                nameGroup: nameGroup,
                createDate: createDate
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
                $('#session,#start,#end,#useFlag,#createDate,#nameGroup').val('');
                $('#modal-default2').modal('hide');
                viewschedule();
            }
        })
    });
```

i can add the first data succesfully but after the modal closed and add the second data on my database there are some coloms that missing from it

Comment: I don't under stand why you need to pass the session data in the payload.  Your session data will be accessible from the controller anyhow.  `canteen/CanteenManagement/addG` can be written as a string _inside_ of `base_url()`.  I don't know that I'd pass datetime from js either -- just use the more trustworthy datetime from the server/controller/model/database. The _create_datetime_ columns in my database tables, usually have a default value of the `CURRENT_DATETIME` so that that value doesn't need to be passed in during INSERT queries.

Comment: What is the state/status/existence of the `id = "modal-default2"` element after `modal('hide')` is called the first time?  Do you have anything actually calling `modal('show')`?

Comment: Those `let` (single-use) variable declarations appear to be unnecessary -- just write those values directly in your `data` object.  I prefer to use a different variable name for receiving the response payload from ajax -- to avoid developer confusion.  I prefer to clear field values when a modal is opened as opposed to when the modal is closed.